# Multilingual queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: full-text-search, multilingual, elasticsearch

Let's say we have the following mapping in ElasticSearch.

```
{
  "content": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "locale_container": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "english": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "english",
                "search_analyzer": "english",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "english",
                "search_analyzer": "english",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              }
            }
          },
          "german": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "german",
                "search_analyzer": "german",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "german",
                "search_analyzer": "german",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              }
            }
          },
          "russian": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "russian",
                "search_analyzer": "russian",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "russian",
                "search_analyzer": "russian",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              }
            }
          },
          "italian": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "italian",
                "search_analyzer": "italian",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "italian",
                "search_analyzer": "italian",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "store": "yes"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a particular user queries the index, we can take her culture from her settings, i.e. we know which analyzer to use. How can we formulate a query which will search only "title" and "text" fields in her own language (let's say, German) and use German analyzer to tokenize the search query?

Comment: It's certainly possible with mapping like this, but haven't you considered having separate indexes for each language? It would reduce duplication in the configuration and make adding new languages easier.

Comment: Actually, I have. But to me it makes more sense like this. This is a very simplified mapping. In the actual one documents have very few language-dependent fields, and a whole lot of language-independent fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the example to use `standard` analyzer for 'English' and `simple` (no stopping) for 'French'. For document like this:

```
{
  id: "abc",
  locale_container: {
    english: {
      title: "abc to ABC",
      text: ""
    },
    french: {
      title: "def to DEF",
      text: ""
    }
  }
}
```

The following queries do the trick:

- `locale_container.english.title:abc` -> returns the document
- `locale_container.french.title:def` -> returns the document as well
- `locale_container.english.title:to` -> doesn't return anything, since 'to' is a stopword
- `locale_container.french.title:to` -> returns the document